# Logging chat coversations in Jabberd2

Tags: logging, chat

We have provided a chat application to our clients. We have jabberd2 running as our chat server. Currently we are using Bandersnatch for logging all the chat messages into the database. The issue with using Bandersnatch is that the server load increases when there are more than 50 users logged in at the same time.

Can you suggest a better way to log the chat messages? I am currently trying to understand the jabberd source code so as to add a logging function in the source code itself. It would be very helpful if you could at least let me know which files to update in order to get this going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jabberd2 built-in logging feature.
https://github.com/Jabberd2/jabberd2/commit/cc284d2d65

You will need to build Git copy though, as this feature is not released as a tarball yet.
https://github.com/Jabberd2/jabberd2/tarball/master